# How do i enable media option on android emulator with command line

Tags: android, android-emulator

in my app i am recording speech so that i need to set up my emulator able to record speech.
i have searched in the google i got some solution that is need to start emulator by manually with media option. i use the following cmd but i got error.

```
emulator -avd Test -audio-in MIC
```

i am using Android 2.2(Api 2.2) on windows 7. How do i enable MIC option on my emulator. please help me.

I got the following error:

> ```
> >emulator -avd Test -audio-in MIC
>
> >unknown option: -audio-in
> ```
>
> please use -help for a list of valid options

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to use this example:

```
package com.benmccann.android.hello;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;

/**
 * @author <a href="http://www.benmccann.com">Ben McCann</a>
*/

public class AudioRecorder {

final MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
final String path;

/**
* Creates a new audio recording at the given path (relative to root of SD card).
*/
public AudioRecorder(String path) {
this.path = sanitizePath(path);
}

private String sanitizePath(String path) {
  if (!path.startsWith("/")) {
  path = "/" + path;
 }
 if (!path.contains(".")) {
  path += ".3gp";
 }
 return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + path;
}

/**
 * Starts a new recording.
*/
public void start() throws IOException {
  String state = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
  if(!state.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))  {
    throw new IOException("SD Card is not mounted.  It is " + state + ".");
 }

 // make sure the directory we plan to store the recording in exists
 File directory = new File(path).getParentFile();
  if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) {
  throw new IOException("Path to file could not be created.");
 }

 recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
 recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
 recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
 recorder.setOutputFile(path);
 recorder.prepare();
 recorder.start();
}

/**
* Stops a recording that has been previously started.
*/
public void stop() throws IOException {
recorder.stop();
recorder.release();
}

}
```

Hope this help you. Let us know how it goes, or if you need further help.

Comment: thanks for the coding i have exact set of coding. my query is set up emulator able to recording speech. emulator -avd Test -audio-in MIC gives error. Is it possible on emulator to enable MIC?

Comment: in emulator i cannot get audio recording